# When UITableViewCell's accessoryType was inited?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using storyboard for UITableView prototype cell and set the `accessoryType` to `Disclosure Indicator`. The arrow one ">". I want to know when the arrow image was added or where can i get it correctly?

Here is the `UIImageView` i want to get.

[image]

My `test()` function below prints `[]`, only when i scroll the `tableview` then it prints correct.

```
[<UIImageView: 0x7fc614766050; frame = (0 0; 8 13); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x618000435f00>> - (null)]
```

I also tried:
`cellForRowAt` and `willDisplay`, both can't get the `UIImageView` only if by scrolling the `tableView` it works.

My customize `UITableViewCell` class:

```
class TestCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        test()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        test()
        self.accessoryType
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        test()
    }

    func test() {
        print(subviews[2].subviews)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        test()
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you override layoutSubviews of the custom cell class and when that is called, delegate to super class first and then check the view hierarchy over and over till you find it.

it is the best you get. not fool proof as you deal with private view hierarchy that isnt yours ;) but it works - we did it for years.

note too that the view hierarchy can change between any iOS releases. it isnt like this is public api. so program extra defensively

Comment: Hi @Daij-Djan, Still can't get the image just tried. You know i just don't want to add an extra desired colored arrow image for this. Thank you anyway.